# Enhanced Ecommerce Data Missing

Tags: analytics

I have a question about this issue :
I have transactions with Google Ecommerce and it comes ok, but now I need make refund. I turn on  Enhanced Ecommerce on Google Analytics account then add code but wait 2 days and nothing happened. I don't see any refund. Please help, what I'm doing wrong?

Here code sample :

```
<script>
(function(i,s,o,g,r,a,m){i['GoogleAnalyticsObject']=r;i[r]=i[r]||function(){
(i[r].q=i[r].q||[]).push(arguments)},i[r].l=1*new Date();a=s.createElement(o),
m=s.getElementsByTagName(o)[0];a.async=1;a.src=g;m.parentNode.insertBefore(a,m)
})(window,document,'script','//www.google-analytics.com/analytics.js','ga');

ga('create', 'UA-xxxxxxx-x', 'auto');
ga('require', 'ec');
ga('ec:setAction', 'refund', {
'id': 'xxxxxx'
});
ga('ec:setAction', 'refund', {
'id': 'xxxxxx'
});

ga('send', 'pageview');
</script>
```

Answer (score 1):

It's not necessary to activate enhanced ecommerce tracking if you only are going to use the refunds functionality. 
You can stick to the classic ecommerce tracking and fire a transaction with the values in negative.

In case you want to know to which transaction corresponds the refund you can use the same transaction ID and add a some indicator, so you would get:

Regular transaction:

```
ID 1234: shipping 30 taxes 21 revenue 100
```

Refunded transaction (negative values):

```
ID refunded_1234: shipping -30 taxes -21 revenue -100
```

In enhanced ecommerce transactions are slightly different, you have to set the transaction and then add an action of type "purchase", probably the "refund" action expects a previous "purchase" action and that's why it does not work.

Comment: In case you want to "reverse" the transaction you have to use the same ID as stated in the documentation
https://support.google.com/analytics/answer/1037443?hl=en